# What does :? operator do in bash?

Tags: bash, operators

I have an expression like this in a bash file:

```
MY_NEW_VAR="path/${MY_VARIABLE:?}"
```

What does :? operator mean?

Comment: [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a question mark in bash variable parameter expansion as in ${var?}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889302/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-question-mark-in-bash-variable-parameter-expansion-as-i)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `$MY_VARIABLE` exists and isn't null, return it's value.
If it doesn't exist, or is null, print the error message you're able to set.

```
MY_NEW_VAR='path/${MY_VARIABLE:?"error message"}'
```

If no error message is given, it return `parameter null or not set`.