# What does "-?" mean in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have this script I am looking at, learning scripting but I cannot figure out what this line means:

```
if [[ $1 = "-?" ]]
```

I understand the `$1` is first argument, but the after the equals I cannot figure it out the `-?`.h

```
if [[ $1 = "-?" ]]
    then
    echo "Use is: 235.sh <username>"
    exit 1
```

Comment: The question-mark after the hyphen means it is questionable the hyphen will be there. Also see [What is the meaning of a question mark in bash variable parameter expansion as in ${var?}?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8889302/608639)

Comment: are you sure it is not `if [[ $1 =~ "-?" ]]`?

Comment: @Allan no I do not see the ~

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420994/bash-regex-match-string
for regular expression in if statement,

usually string comparisons take single square braket!
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a question mark in bash variable parameter expansion as in ${var?}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889302/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-question-mark-in-bash-variable-parameter-expansion-as-i)

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be checking to see if the first argument is a string equal to -?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by running:

```
# [[ "a" = "-?" ]] && echo true
# [[ "-a" = "-?" ]] && echo true
# [[ "a-?" = "-?" ]] && echo true
# [[ "-?" = "-?" ]] && echo true
true
```

I would guess that is comparing something to the string "-?".

Comment: Is the something the $1, or the argument? You should also be careful about globbing when running this check.

Comment: This is correct. The canonical flag now is `--help`, but `-?` used to be the standard and is still commonly seen.