# Validate bash script arguments

Tags: bash

I am trying to do something like this to make a script to perform backups if they have failed. I am taking in the environment as argument to the script.

The one thing i am unsure on how to do is that i want to verify $1 to only include some predefined values. The predefined values should be something like tst, prd, qa, rpt. Anyone?

```
#!/bin/bash
ENVIRONMENT=$1 
BACKUPDATE=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")
BACKUPFILE="$ENVIRONMENT".backup."$BACKUPDATE".tar.gz

if [ $1 ==  "" ] 
 then
 echo "No environment specified"
 exit
elif [ -f "$BACKUPFILE" ]; then
   echo "The file '$BACKUPFILE' exists."
else
   echo "The file '$BACKUPFILE' in not found."
   exec touch "$BACKUPFILE"
fi
```

Comment: One-liner for the first test: `[[ -z "$1" ]] && echo "No environment specified" && exit 1`. And you don't need to `exec touch`. `touch` is enough on its own.

Comment: @Matthieu Shorter one-liner: `: ${1:?No environment specified}`

Comment: @chepner I *knew* there was something around, thanks! (Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889302/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-question-mark-in-bash-variable-parameter-expansion-as-i)

Comment: `[ "$1" = "" ]`, or just `[ -z "$1" ]`. Always quote your expansions, and don't use `==`; it isn't standardized in [the POSIX specification for `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case`:

```
case "$1" in
    tst) echo "Backing up Test style" ;;
    prd)
        echo "Production backup"
        /etc/init.d/myservice stop
        tar czf ...
        /etc/init.d/myservice start
        ;;
    qa) echo "Quality skipped" ;;
    rpt)
        echo "Different type of backup"
        echo "This could be another processing"
        ...
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown backup type"
        exit 2
        ;;
esac
```

Note the double `;;` to end each case, and the [convenient use of pattern matching](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case).

Edit: following your comment and @CharlesDuffy suggestion, if you want to have all valid options in an array and test your value against *any* of them (hence having the same piece of code for *all* valid values), you can use an [associative array](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays):

```
declare -A valids=(["tst"]=1 ["prd"]=1 ["qa"]=1 ["rpt"]=1)
if [[ -z ${valids[$1]} ]] ; then
    echo "Invalid parameter value"
    # Any other processing here ...
    exit 1
fi
# Here your parameter is valid, proceed with processing ...
```

This works by having a value (here `1` but it could be anything else in that case) assigned to *every* valid parameter. So any *invalid* parameter will be null and the `-z` test will trigger.

Credits go to him.

Comment: @runegjo you can edit your question with a list of choices and we'll show you some examples :) Each case expression corresponds to one of the possible choices, and you put the corresponding code between the `)` and the `;;`

Comment: BTW, note that TLDP, and the ABS in particular, is somewhat notorious for outdated information and examples that showcase bad practices. The [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) was written specifically to be a replacement without these faults. There's a reason the ABS isn't listed in the "Books and Resources" section of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info; please consider linking to the official manual, the [bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org), or the Guide instead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you for the valuable info about the source. I edited my answer with a link to bash-hackers' wiki, that I used quite a lot some time ago.

Comment: @runegjo I added Charles Duffy's comment in an edit. See if it works better for you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I used your comment to edit my answer. If you at your own answer, I'll rollback that edit.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many different values you have, what about a `case` statement? It even allows for globbing.

```
case $1 in
  (John)   printf "Likes Yoko\n";;
  (Paul)   printf "Likes to write songs\n";;
  (George) printf "Harrison\n";;
  (Ringo)  printf "Da drumma\n";;
  (*)      printf "Management, perhaps?\n";;
esac
```

On another note, if you can you should avoid unportable bashisms like the `[[` test operator (and use `[` if you can, e.g. `if [ "$1" = "John" ]; then ...; fi`.)

Comment: Oh it works with `(` at the beginning of the case expression? I don't have a computer to test right now.

Comment: See [why is `[]` preferred over `[[]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-ba)

Comment: @Matthieu: Thanks for the help on the [[ ]]. They are now removed.

Comment: @runegjo it's up to you in the end: `[[ ]]` is more flexible and can be used safely if you know `bash` is available on your machines (and it usually is).

Comment: @Matthieu Yes, the initial `(` is optional. I always use it because I (and vi) like matched parentheses.

Comment: @Jens thanks for confirming. It also looks better (and the vi point is very valid! ;))

Comment: @Jens, ...bashisms? `[[` is a ksh-ism that pretty much every extended shell has adopted, and for good reason; making `[[` syntax recognized by the parser allows features (like glob matching) that `[` can't do, and safety features (like recognizing, with complete certainty, the difference between syntax and data; whereas `[` has needed to have features marked obsolescent to avoid ambiguity).

Comment: Could the $1 varialble be validated against an array of valid values?

Comment: @runegjo, against an *associative* array (the data structure some other languages call a map or a hash), trivially and quickly. For a regular numerically-indexed array you'd need to loop, and that would be much less efficient.

Comment: `declare -A validValues=( ["validOne"]=1 ["validTwo"]=1 ["whatever"]=1 ); if [[ ${validValues[$myValue]} ]]; then echo "$myValue is listed as valid"; fi`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your comment is a better answer than my answer :)