# How to use User Inputs with Slurm

Tags: bash, slurm, sbatch

I'm looking for using inputs in the shell prompt by way of SLURM . For example, when I use a simple bash script like :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo What\'s the path of the files? 

read mypath

echo What\'s the name you want to give to your archive with the files of $mypath? 

read archive_name

echo Ok, let\'s create the archive $archive_name

for i in $mypath/*;
do if [[ -f $i ]]; then
   tar -cvf $archive_name $mypath/*;
   fi;
done
```

And I use in the prompt :

```
bash my_script.sh 

What's the path of the files? 
/the/path/of/the/files
What's the name you want to give to your archive with the files of $mypath?
my_archive.tar
```

And it creates the archive `my_archive.tar` . But now, I have to use that script with SLURM. When I use `sbatch my_script.sh` , that automatically submits the script in a job and I can't add my inputs : `/the/path/of/the/files` and `my_archive.tar`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**Modify the script so that it uses parameters rather than interactive questions.**

The script would then look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mypath=${1?Usage: $0 <mypath> <archive_name>}
archive_name=${2?Usage: $0 <mypath> <archive_name>}    

echo Ok, let\'s create the archive $archive_name

for i in $mypath/*;
do if [[ -f $i ]]; then
   tar -cvf $archive_name $mypath/*;
   fi;
done
```

This script would then be run with `bash my_script.sh /the/path/of/the/files my_archive.tar` rather than `bash my_script.sh` . The first argument is made available in the `$1` variable in the script, the second one is in `$2`, etc. See [this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258603/what-do-0-1-2-mean-in-shell-script).

The syntax `$(1?Usage...)` is a simple way to issue an error message if the script is not run with at least two arguments. See [this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889302/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-question-mark-in-bash-variable-parameter-expansion-as-i)

or,

**Use Expect to answer the questions automatically**

The [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) command is (from the doc)

> a program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script.

You could use an Expect script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn my_script.sh
expect "What's the path of the files?"
send "/the/path/of/the/files\r"
expect -re "What's the name you want to give to your archive with the files of .*"
send "my_archive.tar\r"
expect
```

It gives the following, after making the Expect script executable:

```
$ ./test.expect 
spawn my_script.sh
What's the path of the files?
/the/path/of/the/files
What's the name you want to give to your archive with the files of /the/path/of/the/files?
my_archive.tar
Ok, let's create the archive my_archive.tar
```

You can run the Expect script in a Slurm submission script.